# Visual Studio - Gated Checkin - GIT - TF402455

Tags: git, visual-studio, tfs

**Product information**:

- Microsoft Visual Studio Team Foundation Server Version 15.117.27024.0
- Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 Version 15.9.11

**The problem**: We have set up a GIT repository, and enabled a [gated checkin](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/buckh/gated-checkin-for-git-using-branch-policies-to-run-a-build-in-vsts-and-tfs/) for it. As soon as we do so, we are no longer able to commit any changes to the GIT server.

When a synch or a push is attempted this error is received:
Error encountered while pushing to the remote repository: rejected fake-branch-name -> fake-branch-name (TF402455: Pushes to this branch are not permitted; you must use a pull request to update this branch.)

When a pull request is created then no changes are available from the local repo to commit to the remote repo.

**The question**: How do we commit changes to a repo from visual studio when gated checkins are enabled?

Comment: BTW, I am very new to GIT, so forgive me if I say something wrong or in the wrong manner.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a new development branch from your fake-branch-name and commit into it [Create a new Git branch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/create-branch?view=azure-devops)
2. Create a pull request from the development branch into your fake-branch-name [Create a pull request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/pullrequest?view=azure-devops)

Check the online documentation of [Azure Repos Git tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/gitworkflow?view=azure-devops)

Comment: Coming from a TFS perspective, that seems awfully convoluted. Local repo -> dev branch -> feature branch.... just to get gated checkins. :|

Comment: @SpaceGhost440 After TFVC, it requires some time to change our habits :)

Answer (score 0):

[Branch Policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies?view=azure-devops) are used to implement gated check-ins in git. You can check the following steps to set up a gated check-in on the `master` branch:

1. Create a build pipeline to build and verify the project in `master` branch.
2. Set branch policy for `master` branch:

[image]

3. Create a new branch `branch` from `master` branch, and commit changes into `branch`.

[image]

4. Create a pull request as the screenshot below shows:

[image]

5. Check whether there is a build validation:

[image]

6. If the validation is passed, When you complete the pull request, the changes will be merged into `master` branch.